# fetch response on client with form-data from server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data

I am using the Node 'form-data' module on an Express server to construct a multipart/form-data response to a fetch request from the client browser (which also a multipart using fetch, but is received fine at the server using multer on the server). When server sends back a form-data response I get error at the fetch client on receipt of response - "Could not parse content as FormData."(the native FormData) (Note: This is different from Express parsers not parsing multipart, this is the native fetch client on browser not parsing a node form-data) What am I doing wrong in the server response or client repsonse processing?

At the server:

```
const formdata = require('form-data')
app.post(req,res,next) {
// ... process the request and construct form-data response...//

var form = new formdata(); 
form.append("serverResponse", "Reply from server to fetch request from client")
res.end(form.getBuffer())
}
```

At the Client

```
//... send request to server which has no problem, but returncannot decode the response as FormData

 return fetch(  pRequest   )
    .then(response => { 
      return response.formData()   //***this throws 'Could not parse content as FormData***
    }
    .then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the header "Content-Type" of your response to "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Apparently you also have to add the boundary to the header. I ended up doing this:
res.setHeader('Content-Type', \`multipart/form-data; boundary=${formdata.getBoundary()}\`)

Comment: This: res.set(form_data.getHeaders());